# Comment distinguer « reporter », « repousser » et « différer » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je connais des mots pour désigner « remettre à plus tard » mais je ne sais guère comment je dois les utiliser. La combinaison de mots « Remettre à plus tard » a l’air d’une bonne façon de dire, mais j’aimerais trouver des formules raccourcies. Le mot *remettre* sans y ajouter quelque chose pour désigner « remettre à plus tard » passe peut-être mal parce qu’il veut dire de nombreuses choses.

Les mots que je connais sont *reporter, repousser* et *différer* . Pourriez-vous me dire comment ces mots ce rapportent, et m’éclaircir sur leurs sous-entendus ?

**Ma propre tentative de les comprendre**

- Je pense que *reporter*, est un mot assez neutre qui exprime bien «
  remettre à plus tard ».
- Quant à repousser, j’ai parfois peur que l’on dise seulement « je
  repousse la rencontre » quand on n’en a pas envie.
- Le mot différer veut souvent dire « être dissemblable ».
  Heureusement, cet emploi ne permet pas d’objet, donc je crois qu’il n'y a qu'une façon de comprendre une phrase comme « Ces gens diffèrent la rencontre ». Je ne sais toutefois pas si cet emploi est usité.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je pense que ta tentative est assez proche, voici mon avis :

- **Reporter** : probablement le plus neutre d'entre tous. Il fait partie du langage courant.
- **Repousser** : on sens une certaine réluctance comme tu l'as souligné. Un peu plus familier que reporter.
- **Différer** : plus soutenu que les précédents et moins courant dans la vie de tous les jours à part dans le milieu des médias (TV) comme pour "*un match en différé*", i.e. décalé par rapport au direct.
- **Décaler** : assez neutre, tout comme reporter, avec un connotation professionnelle. Très utilisé pour les rendez-vous surtout ("*décaler un rendez-vous*").
- **Remettre** : surtout entendu dans "*remettre à plus tard*" ou "*remettre au lendemain*" avec parfois un sous entendu de procrastination.
- **Ajourner** : de nos jours presque exclusivement entendu dans un cadre juridique ou administratif, cela signifie interrompre une procédure pour la remettre à plus tard (que la date sois connue, "*ajournement à huitaine*" par exemple; ou non, "*ajournement sine die*").
- **Reprogrammer** : utilisé pour un événement dont la date est modifiée à priori. (*Déprogrammer* correspondant à une annulation).

Mis à part ajourner qui ne possède (à ma connaissance) que cette signification, tous les autres verbes peuvent être employés autrement (Exemples : reporter comme synonyme de ramener, repousser comme synonyme d'éloigner, différer pour être dissemblables, décaler pour un décalage spatial, remettre pour donner, reprogrammer pour charger un programme différent). Le contexte permet assez généralement de faire la distinction et il me vient aucune tournure où leur signification serait particulièrement ambiguë.

Bonus :

- **Procrastiner** : repousser (telle ou telle obligation) de manière chronique.

*Edit : ajout de reprogrammer et procrastiner (en bonus) suite aux commentaires de Romain Valeri.*

Comment: (+1) Excellent catalogue de synonymes. A l'extrême rigueur on pourrait ajouter *procrastiner* pour le sens (assez proche) de *repousser (telle ou telle obligation) de manière chronique*

Comment: ...et peut-être aussi *reprogrammer*, citons le parce qu'il existe, mais il me semble qu'il n'apporte pas de nuance cruciale.

Comment: @RomainVALERI *reprogrammer* dans le cadre d'un festival, d'un spectacle veut aussi dire que l'on remet à nouveau au programme quelque chose d'ancien, cela ne veut pas obligatoirement dire que l'ancien programme a été annulé, cela peut aussi dire qu'il était très bon, qu'il y avait beaucoup de public et qu'il a de nouveau été mis à l'affiche sous la pression des spectateurs. J'ai surtout entendu dire que le programme était annulé, reporté, que les dates avaient changées, éventuellement qu'il avait été ***déplacé***.

Comment: Pour ma part j'ai beaucoup plus lu/entendu "reporter *sine die*" que "ajourner *sine die*". Et et google à l'air d'accord avec moi.